# Error "Variable de objeto o bloque With no establecido" en VBA

Tags: vba, zip

Buscando, he localizado cómo descargar los archivos de un correo a la carpeta que necesito, ahora me encuentro con el problema que vienen comprimidos en .zip y tengo que descomprimirlos para cargarlos en la BBDD.

Buscando, he visto este código, que me da error en el ultimo paso.
Me pueden ayudar no se donde esta el error y buscando no encuentro nada.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Sub Descomprimir()

Dim Destino As String
Dim Origen As String
Dim oApp As Object

Destino = "C:\Users\PTbarbera\Desktop\descagasDatos\pruebaZip"
Origen = "C:\Users\PTbarbera\Desktop\descagasDatos\prueba.zip"

 Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  oApp.NameSpace(Destino).CopyHere 
  oApp.NameSpace(Origen).Items

End Sub
```

El ultimo paso es el que me da el error:  `oApp.NameSpace(Destino).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Origen).Items`.

¿No sé si tengo que activar alguna referencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí hay otro ejemplo de cómo descomprimir un archivo. 
la macro descomprime el archivo zip en una carpeta fija `"C:\test\"`

```
Sub Unzip()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FileNameFolder As Variant
    Dim DefPath As String

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Zip Files (*.zip), *.zip", _
                                        MultiSelect:=False)
    If Fname = False Then
        'No hacer nada
    Else
        'Carpeta de destino
        DefPath = "C:\test\"    ' Cambia a tu ruta / variable
        If Right(DefPath, 1) <> "\" Then
            DefPath = DefPath & "\"
        End If

        FileNameFolder = DefPath

        '        'Borre todos los archivos en la carpeta DefPath primero si lo desea
        '        En caso de error reanudar
        '        Kill DefPath & "*.*"
        '        En caso de error, vaya a 0 (GoTo 0)

        'Extraiga los archivos en la carpeta Destino
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameFolder).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).items

        MsgBox "Aquí encuentras los archivos: " & FileNameFolder

        On Error Resume Next
        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.deletefolder Environ("Temp") & "\Temporary Directory*", True
    End If
End Sub
```

> Aquí hay otros ejemplos útiles (traducir del inglés):
>
> - [Descomprimir archivo(s) con el programa predeterminado de Windows
>     (VBA)](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm)
> - [Extraiga el archivo .rar en Vba Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42137668/8933039)
> - [Extraiga el archivo comprimido del correo de Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480900/8933039)

Comment: Muchas Gracias J.Rodriguez, Funciona perfectamente. saludos.

Comment: Hola, este código es el que uso y funciona perfecto!, lo único que no que le falta es poner la rurta directamente donde tengo los archivos guardados.